# click on headline to toggle a set of multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have sets of checkboxes and a rotated h4 next to each set.

I'm trying to make it so that when i click the h4 alla related checkboxes are 
-all checked - unless they were alreade all checked, if so uncheck all.

[image]

jQuery the closest I've come so far:

```
    jQuery(".sidewaysHeader h4").click(function() {
        var now = $(this).attr('id');
        $('input:checkbox[name="'+ now +'"]').attr('checked', true );
    });
```

The HTML:

```
        <div class="sidewaysHeader"><h4 id="halsa">Hälsa</h4></div>
        <input type="checkbox" value="idrott" id="idrott" name="halsa" /><label for="idrott">Idrott</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="dans" id="dans" name="halsa" /><label for="dans">Dans</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="hemkunskap" id="hemkunskap" name="halsa" /><label for="hemkunskap">Hemkunskap</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="mat-och-boende" id="mat-och-boende" name="halsa" /><label for="mat-och-boende">Mat & Boende</label>
```

Comment: I'm using: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.sidewaysHeader h4').click(function() {
   var now = $(this).attr('id');
   if($('input:checkbox[name="'+ now +'"]:not(:checked)').length >= 1)
     $('input:checkbox[name="'+ now +'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
   else
      $('input:checkbox[name="'+ now +'"]').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

What this will do is, look for any unchecked input within the group, if any checkbox is not already checked then check all, otherwise, we uncheck all because we know they are all checked.

Answer (score 0):

actually this works

http://jsfiddle.net/tuhLG/2/

Answer (score 0):

what i understand it you want to check and uncheck all the checkboxs on click on header. and if any one of them is already checked then check them all. you can do it like this

```
jQuery(".sidewaysHeader h4").click(function() {
    var elems = $('input:checkbox[name="'+ $(this).attr('id') +'"]');
    elems.attr('checked', elems.filter(':checked').length != elems.length);
});
```

**fiddle example :** http://jsfiddle.net/tuhLG/6/